# Pairwise match and merging of overlapping sequences in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, overlapping

I have a pandas dataframe, containing four columns; a reference sequence, a read from that reference sequence, and start/end positions of that read. I am trying to iterate over this dataframe and check rows pairwise to see if the reads overlap based on their start and end positions, and merge them if they do. Next, I want to check this newly merged read to the next read in the dataframe to see if they overlap, and merge these as well if they do. So far I have put my data in a pandas DataFrame, but maybe I'm starting to believe that this maybe not be the optimal solution, and maybe e.g. a dictionary would be more suited for this kind of operation.

I have tried multiple things, without any luck, so I am hoping that one of you wonderful people may be able to come up with a solution from the data:

```py
data = [
        ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "ABCDE", 1, 5],
        ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "DEFGHIJK", 4, 11],
        ["ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ", "IJKLMNOPQRST", 9, 20],
        ["TESTINGONETWOTHREE", "TEST", 1, 4],
        ["TESTINGONETWOTHREE", "NGONE", 6, 10],
        ["TESTINGONETWOTHREE", "NETWOTHR", 9, 16],
]

df = pd.DataFrame(
        data, columns=["reference", "read", "start", "end"]
)


print(df)
                    reference          read  start  end
0  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ         ABCDE      1    5
1  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ      DEFGHIJK      4   11
2  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  IJKLMNOPQRST      9   20
3          TESTINGONETWOTHREE          TEST      1    4
4          TESTINGONETWOTHREE         NGONE      6   10
5          TESTINGONETWOTHREE      NETWOTHR      9   16
```

In this case, I would like to end up with a new dataframe (or dictionary) that has the merged reads, the reference sequence that they are from and their start and stop positions, like so:

```py
                    reference                  read  start  end
0  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ  ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRST      1   20
1          TESTINGONETWOTHREE                  TEST      1    4
2          TESTINGONETWOTHREE           NGONETWOTHR      6   16
```

I would very much appreciate any help on this :)
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a custom group to identify the non overlapping stretches, then use it to aggregate with `join`/`min`/`max`:

```
group = df['start'].gt(df.groupby('reference')['end'].shift()-1).cumsum()
# [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1]

(df.groupby(['reference', group])
   .agg({'read': ''.join, 'start': 'min', 'end': 'max'})
)
```

output:

```
                                                   read  start  end
reference                                                          
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ 0  ABCDEDEFGHIJKIJKLMNOPQRST      1   20
TESTINGONETWOTHREE         0                       TEST      1    4
                           1              NGONENETWOTHR      6   16
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you very much, this is brilliant! An additional question: Say I allow for a small gap between the sequences while merging, so that reads in close vicinity (smaller gap than a defined threshold) are still merged, including the gap. E.g the read "TEST" and "NGONETWOTHR" only have a gap of two, and if this is smaller than my threshold, I still want to create a merged read from these two inlcuding the gap, so the resulting read would be "TESTINGONETWOTHR". Would it be possible to implement this in your answer as well? :)

Comment: @OMMJREN I am not sure what you mean by gap? you can change the `-1` in the code to allow some difference between the rows (try `-1+2` to allow a gap of 2)

Comment: Actually I see that this is not exactly what I was asking for. The reads are concatenated, but the overlaps are included twice, e.g. the first read should be "ABCDEFGIJKLMNOPQRST". The suggested solution includes the two overlaps "DE" and "IJK" twice, so that the it becomes "ABCDE*DE*FGHIJK*IJK*LMNOPQRST". I wanted to only include these overlaps once. And what I meant by gap is if you look at the original data, the end position of the read "TEST" is 4, only 2 positions in the reference sequence from the start position of the read "NGONETWOTHR". I want to allow this small gap, and merge

Comment: So that the final read would include the gap as well, and become "TESTINGONETWOTHR" :)

Comment: I see, no then the logic is different